# facebook border doubts

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I have a tableview and I want that every cell has the same border like Facebook post cell as in this image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIPz0.png)

Can you help me please?

Update:

I set the layer in this way in the awakeFromNib of the cell:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        //self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4

    }
```

but I dont get the same facebook's effect.

Comment: you mean that box?

Comment: yes it's correct

Comment: the same border of the box

Comment: I edited the layer property of cell but i'm not be able to achive the same result

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: no, I want to do this by code

Comment: provide some code.. so that i can help you

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: you can set this easily by using storyboard

Comment: ok tell me how i have to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Tableview cell like this

[image]

in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method set

```
cell.cardView.setsetCardView()
```

The setCardView function is

```
func setCardView()
  {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    let shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    let shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 0
    let shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.gray
    let shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
    layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}

Try it with a larger border width to make sure that the colour is correctly set and is being drawn correctly.

I did this in a playground:

[image: Storyboard with Live View]